# Enable mod_python and mod_wsgi module

Tags: wsgi, mod-python, apache-modules

Can I use `mod_python.so` and `mod_wsgi.so` at the same time on *Apache Web Server* defining different directories for each of them. At the moment I can not enable them both in my *apache config file* at the same time using `LoadModule`.
`mod_wsgi` for *Django* and  `mod_python` for .py and .psp scripts.

Answer (score 3):

For recent versions of mod_wsgi no you cannot load them at the same time as mod_wsgi will prevent it as mod_python thread code doesn't use Python C API for threads properly and causes various problems.

Short answer is that you shouldn't be using mod_python any more. Use a proper Python web framework with a more modern template system instead.

If for some reason you really don't want to do that, go back and use mod_wsgi 3.5.